# Manipular archivos con Batch

Tags: windows, consola, cmd

Quiero hacer un BackUp de una carpeta con todos sus archvios, llamada "DATA" , y hacer un Respaldo, cada vez que ejecute en archivo .BAT, se realiza su backup.

Comment: Te recomiendo investigar cómo puedes copiar y pegar una carpeta en otra ubicación.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Quieres copiar tu carpeta "DATA" a otra carpeta con otro nombre? Copiar una carpeta es tan simple como invocar el comando [XCOPY](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true), pero no es claro si esto es lo que quieres. Si preguntas CÓMO hacer algo, debes explicar QUÉ quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez te sirva el siguiente link:
https://www.speedguide.net/articles/how-to-backup-using-batch-files-1547

Tiene un ejemplo de código:

```
@echo off
:: variables
set drive=G:\Backup
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

echo ### Backing up My Documents...
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents" "%drive%\My Documents"

echo ### Backing up Favorites...
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" "%drive%\Favorites"

echo ### Backing up email and address book (Outlook Express)...
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Address Book" "%drive%\Address Book"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities" "%drive%\Outlook Express"

echo ### Backing up email and contacts (MS Outlook)...
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook" "%drive%\Outlook"

echo ### Backing up the Registry...
if not exist "%drive%\Registry" mkdir "%drive%\Registry"
if exist "%drive%\Registry\regbackup.reg" del "%drive%\Registry\regbackup.reg"
regedit /e "%drive%\Registry\regbackup.reg"

:: use below syntax to backup other directories...
:: %backupcmd% "...source directory..." "%drive%\...destination dir..."

echo Backup Complete!
@pause
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes descargar zip desde esta ruta (busca `zip.exe`)

http://stahlworks.com/dev/

Luego, en el batch de windows (cmd) puedes usar:

```
zip -r data.zip data
```

Listo, con eso creas un archivo data.zip con el contenido de la carpeta

Comment: Cuidado al bajar archivos ejecutables desde páginas que no son claramente "oficiales" (es decir, los responsables o distribuidores de ese software). Más aún si no ofrecen https://

Answer (score -1):

Esta tarea es la ejecuto en **Linux** para hacer `backups`:

```
#!/bin/bash
directorio="ruta_del_diretorio"
if [ "$(ls -A $directorio)" ]; then
cp /ruta/al/directorio/origen/* /ruta/al/directorio/destino
fi
```

Comment: esta tarea es la ejecuto en linux para hacer backups

Comment: Gracias por tu interés en ayudar, tu solución es para linux y la pregunta se refiere a windows. Saludos